# Nuxt Vuetifi, переопределение стилей scss

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scss, nuxt.js

В продакшен версии мои стили перебиваются стилями vuetify.

nuxt.conf:

```
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    titleTemplate: 'runCRM -  программа для курьерской службы',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Курьерская программа доставки и приложение для курьеров' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '~/assets/variables.scss',
    '~/assets/main.scss'
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa'
  ],
  proxy: {
    // Simple proxy
    '/api': 'http://127.0.0.1:3333'
  },
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
    prefix: '/api/v1',
    proxy: true
  },
  /*
  ** vuetify module configuration
  ** https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
  */
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        light: {
          primary: colors.purple,
          secondary: colors.grey.darken1,
          accent: colors.shades.black,
          error: colors.red.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extractCSS: true,
    filenames: {
      css: ({ isDev }) => isDev ? '[name].css' : '[name].[contenthash].css'
    },
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```